# Chart JS tooltip labels spaced as spaceBetween

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip

I have a stacked bar chart where the tooltip shows Label: $value & I would like this to be set as space-between so Label is aligned to the left & $value is aligned to the right, allowing all the numerical values to align. For example:

```
Label 1:     $10,000
Label 2:     $50,000
Label 3:    $100,000
```

Here is the calculator. Just press the compound button to show the chart.

https://youthful-euclid-784d05.netlify.app

ChartJS options:

```
    // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "bottom"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 16,
          fontFamily: "Roboto Condensed"
        },
        
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Year',
          fontSize: 16,
          fontFamily: "Roboto Condensed"
        },
        stacked: true,
      }],

      yAxes: [{

        
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontSize: 12,
          fontFamily: "Roboto Condensed",
          
        
          callback: function (value, index, values) {
            if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
              return (
                numeral(value).format("$0a")
                // "$" + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
              );
            } else {
              // return "$" + value;
            }
          },
        },
      }, ],
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels : {
          fontSize: 14,
          fontFamily: "Roboto Condensed",
         
      },
      
    },
    chart: {

    },
    tooltips: {
      // displayColors: false,
      yAlign: "bottom",

      callbacks: {
        title: function (tooltip, data) {
          return `After ${tooltip[0].label} Years`;
          },

                    label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                        return `    ${data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label}:  ${formatCurrency(tooltipItems.value)}`;
                    },
                    
                      },
      
          // bodyAlign: "center",
          titleFontSize: 15,
          titleMarginBottom: 10,
          bodySpacing: 10,
          bodyFontSize: 12,
          mode: "x",
          xPadding: 10,
          yPadding: 10,
         
      // bodySpacing: "5"
    },
  }
```

Comment: I tried calculate number of space needed to fit label into fixed length. I successfully get correct number but even then chartjs tooltip showed values not perfectly aligned.

Comment: Got a solution?

Comment: The question is pretty much useless without a working demo

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can think off, is to create a custom tooltip. then you have full control over the styling and data.
Im not sure 100% how you want the end result to look like, but i will add here example that will cover everything you need to know in order to create your own tooltip.
(following chart js docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/html.html)

(Codesandbox example at the bottom of the answer)

First this is how the options object will look like:

```
options: {
...   
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
      position: "nearest",
      external: (a) => externalTooltipHandler(a),
      },
   },
 ...
}
```

now this is how the `externalTooltipHandler` function will look like.

First we need to create an helper function to get the tooltip element,
Here we are trying to get the tooltip element, and checking if exist, if not we are creating one and adding some style to it. and returning the tooltip element. (we will call this function inside `externalTooltipHandler`)

```
const getOrCreateTooltip = (chart) => {
    let tooltipEl = chart.canvas.parentNode.querySelector("div");

    if (!tooltipEl) {
      tooltipEl = document.createElement("div");
      tooltipEl.style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)";
      tooltipEl.style.borderRadius = "3px";
      tooltipEl.style.color = "white";
      tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
      tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = "none";
      tooltipEl.style.position = "absolute";
      tooltipEl.style.transform = "translate(-50%, 0)";
      tooltipEl.style.transition = "all .1s ease";

      const table = document.createElement("table");
      table.style.margin = "0px";

      tooltipEl.appendChild(table);
      chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
    }

    return tooltipEl;
  };
```

now `externalTooltipHandler` - here we will get the information from the argument, chart info and tooltip info. we will get the tooltip element from the function above, we will loop through titles and bodies - in order to generate and style each.
I will try to break it down with comments in the code.

*Notice the root element is a table, that why im using tr, th and td

In the function above you can see it creates a table element. you can feel free to use divs if easier for you to style.

```
const externalTooltipHandler = (context) => {
    // Tooltip Element
    const { chart, tooltip } = context;
    // ---- Getting the tooltip element ----//
    const tooltipEl = getOrCreateTooltip(chart);

    // Hide if no tooltip
    if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
      tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
      return;
    }

    // Set Text
    if (tooltip.body) {
      const titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
      const bodyLines = tooltip.body.map((b) => b.lines);
      // ---- Creating the label head ----//
      const toolTipTitle = document.createElement("thead");
      // ---- Looping through headers and generating the child element ----//
      titleLines.forEach((title) => {
        const toolTipTitleTr = document.createElement("tr");
        // ---- inserting the label text to the child element and appenidng ----//
        const parent = document.createElement("th");
        const text = document.createTextNode(title);
        parent.appendChild(text);
        toolTipTitleTr.appendChild(parent);
        toolTipTitle.appendChild(toolTipTitleTr);
      });

      // ---- Creating the parent for the label and value - # of votes: 12 ----//
      const colorLabelAndDataParent = document.createElement("tbody");

      // ---- Looping to create for each label and value ----//
      bodyLines.forEach((body, i) => {
        const colorLabelAndDataTr = document.createElement("tr");
        const colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
        // this will create the color before the label.
        const colorDiv = document.createElement("div");
        colorDiv.style.background = colors.backgroundColor;
        colorDiv.style.marginRight = "10px";
        colorDiv.style.height = "10px";
        colorDiv.style.width = "10px";
        colorDiv.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        colorDiv.style.display = "inline-block";

        const labelParent = document.createElement("td");
        const valueParent = document.createElement("td");

        labelParent.style.textAlign = "left";
        valueParent.style.textAlign = "right";
        // ---- Splitting the body by : to get the label and the value seperatly ----//
        const label = document.createTextNode(body[0].split(":")[0]);
        const value = document.createTextNode(body[0].split(":")[1]);

        labelParent.appendChild(colorDiv);
        labelParent.appendChild(label);
        valueParent.appendChild(value); // adding color

        colorLabelAndDataTr.appendChild(labelParent);
        colorLabelAndDataTr.appendChild(valueParent);

        colorLabelAndDataParent.appendChild(colorLabelAndDataTr);
      });
      // ---- Notice the root element is a table, that why im using tr, th and td ----//
      const tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector("table");

      // Remove old children
      while (tableRoot.firstChild) {
        tableRoot.firstChild.remove();
      }
      tableRoot.style.width = "150px";
      tableRoot.style.color = "white";
      // Add new children
      tableRoot.appendChild(toolTipTitle);
      tableRoot.appendChild(colorLabelAndDataParent);
    }
    // ---- Styling for position, i left it here from the docs ---- ///
    const { offsetLeft: positionX, offsetTop: positionY } = chart.canvas;

    // Display, position, and set styles for font
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
    tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + "px";
    tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + "px";
    tooltipEl.style.font = tooltip.options.bodyFont.string;
    tooltipEl.style.padding =
      tooltip.options.padding + "px " + tooltip.options.padding + "px";
  };
```

Basically following this example you can style and customize it how ever you want.

here is an example in codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/strange-https-39zdhy

If it will be easier for you, i can split externalTooltipHandler into multiple small functions that handles different things. anyway i will suggest you to play with the code example. once you get the idea its pretty simple..

One more thing to concider, besides adding styles in js you can simply add classes in js and style in css. should be cleaner.

Comment: Im glad i could help. if you need any further help, let me know.